# Delete and query, without DbContext.SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

Entity know-how question. Given the following code:

```
...
var entitiesToRemove = dbSet.Where (entity => entity.TimeToLive > 5);
dbSet.RemoveRange(entitiesToRemove);
var resultEntities = dbSet.Where(entity => /* some condition that will also match before deleted entities*/);
...
```

Question: Will the beforehand deleted entities also be included in `resultEntities` or not? Do I've to call `DbContext.SaveChanges` after `dbSet.RemoveRange` ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do dbcontext.SaveChanges() before doing further processing.
In dbSet.RemoveRange(entitiesToRemove), EF just have marked those entities for deletion. Which will reflect on db only after you call the SaveChanges().

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think `DbContext.SaveChanges` should go after `dbSet.RemoveRange`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the beforehand deleted entities will be included in `resultEntities`. Beacause, the `RemoveRange` didn't get reflected to the database. And, then when you are getting the results for `resultEntites`, you are querying the database, so it would result in the deleted values as well.

If you don't want the removed values to appear then you should call the `Dbcontext.Savechanges()` after `RemoveRange`.

Hope this helps.